# Why hapi.js is special?

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

I am learning hapi.js, A framework of node.js. I gone through some tutorials but i didn't get the exact specialty of hapi compared to other frameworks.  I want to know why hapi.js is special when compared to other frameworks of node.js. Could anyone help me ?

Comment: Thanks for adding this question, I have also not get proper answer for same...

Answer (score 1):

hapi is special because of many reasons but in particular it is modular and promotes configuration over code approach which helps when managing larger complex business applications.  The modular plugin system enables specific logic to be separated to help with development especially in teams.